# Can I target an indestructible creature with a 'destroy target creature' spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

Of course the spell won't resolve, but is the indestructible creature a legal target for a spell with the effect "destroy target creature"?

For example, can I target [Gideon, Champion of Justice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gideon%2C%20Champion%20of%20Justice), animated by its second ability, with [Rapid Hybridization](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rapid%20Hybridization)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, **Indestructible** creatures are legal targets for spells/abilities that say "destroy target creature."

The spell actually does resolve, but when it attempts to destroy the creature rule 700.4 prevents it from happening. The requirements for a "legal target" for a spell must be a permanent, unless the spell/ability specifies otherwise. **Indestructibility** does not modify the rules for targeting, unlike the rules for protection (702.15b A permanent or player with protection can’t be targeted by spells with the stated quality and can’t be targeted by abilities from a source with the stated quality).

You can target Gideon with [Rapid Hybridization](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rapid%20Hybridization), and when it resolves it will fail to destroy Gideon and will create 3/3 frog owned by Gideon's controller.

> 114.2. Only permanents are legal targets for spells and abilities, unless a spell or ability (a) specifies that it can target an object in another zone or a player, (b) targets an object that can’t exist on the battlefield, such as a spell or ability, or (c) targets a zone.

> 700.4. If a permanent is indestructible, rules and effects can’t destroy it. (See rule 701.6, “Destroy.”) Such permanents are not destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the lethal-damage state-based action (see rule 704.5g). Rules or effects may cause an indestructible permanent to be sacrificed, put into a graveyard, or exiled.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I can see, it's a nice trick to have a 3/3 creature for 1 at instance speed :)

Comment: And note that if, while it's on the stack, another effect is added that removes indestructibility, then the creature *will* be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it says `"destroy target creature that's not indestructible"` than yes, you can target it.

And yes, the spell will resolve.  Gideon won't be destroyed, but his controller will still get his `Frog Lizard`

The same goes for spells that `cannot be countered` and tapping and untapping creatures.`

Answer (score 2):

You can target anything that matches the description given for what's a legal target (unless Shroud, Hexproof or similar prevents you). [Rapid Hybridization](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rapid%20Hybridization) has you pick a *target creature*. Since [Gideon, Champion of Justice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gideon%2C%20Champion%20of%20Justice) is a creature (at this time), you can pick it as the target.

---

But Gideon is indestructible (at this time). It can't be destroyed [CR 700.4], but Rapid Hybridization instructs you to destroy it. *Can't* trumps *do* [CR 101.2], so you're asked to do something impossible.

> 609.3. If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.

So in this case, the following happens:

> <s>Destroy target creature. It can't be regenerated.</s> That creature's controller puts a 3/3 green Frog Lizard creature token onto the battlefield.

Gideon's controller will get to keep Gideon, and he will gain a Frog Lizard.

Answer (score 1):

this is from the ruling section from the gatherer link for 'Rapid Hybridization'

> If Rapid Hybridization resolves and the creature isn’t destroyed
>   (perhaps because it’s indestructible), its controller will still get
>   the Frog Lizard token.

Comment: That only answers half the question since the creature could have become indestructible after it was targeted.