# Grisly Spectacle has two parts if the first part fails does the second still happen

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Grisly Spectacle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrisly%20Spectacle%5d) states:

> Destroy target nonartifact creature. Its controller puts a number of cards equal to that creature's power from the top of his or her library into his or her graveyard.

If a creature is indestructible the first part will have no effect, but will the second part still happen?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. My initial nomination of it as a duplicate was incorrect, I think. In this case there's no fizzling that will occur — Grisly Spectacle just won't destroy the creature but it will still be a valid target.

Comment: @doppelgreener The proposed duplicate handles both the situation of when the target becomes invalid, and when the target doesn't become invalid. Why would this not be a duplicate of that?

Comment: The proposed duplicate is broader, but that should be fine. When someone asks "does summoning sickness prevent the use of activated abilities?" we close it as a duplicate of the question that covers all of the rules surrounding summoning sickness.

Comment: @GendoIkari The answer to that question exclusively deals with when targets become illegal, because the cards being asked about exclusively would be impacted by targets becoming illegal. The duplicate banner here says “this question already has an answer here”, but it doesn't. The dupe target acknowledges there's various kinds of ways spells can fail to execute properly, but the question *isn't* a generic canonical question like our summoning sickness one is. (And if we wanted one, we should probably start fresh rather than adopt that one.)

Comment: @doppelgreener It doesn't though; it specifically talks about the case of the target having an ability that prevents the spell from doing what it tries to do; without the target becoming an invalid target. I agree that it's not a canonical question like the summoning sickness one.

Comment: And although the specific example given in that other question dealt with a target becoming invalid; the question itself was asking for an explanation of both situations; when would a spell fizzle vs when would it try to do as much as possible.

Comment: @GendoIkari Well, I don't think it covers this question, nor that this question is a duplicate, nor that this question has answers there. So I'm leaving my vote to reopen.

Comment: (@GendoIkari Btw, I think my response there came across a bit more argumentative-sounding than I meant. I apologise.)

Comment: @doppelgreener No problem. You haven't convinced me to reopen it myself; but I'll just let it be and see if the necessary votes come in.

Comment: Would [Can I target an indestructible creature with a 'destroy target creature' spell?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11412/6692) be a better duplication target?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can target an indestructible creature with Grisly Spectacle. If you do, the spell will try and fail to destroy the creature, and the spell will mill the creature's controller.

Be aware that you need a creature you can legally target with Grisly Spectacle in order to cast the spell, and the creature needs to still be around and legal to target in order for the mill to happen. You can't for example, Grisly Spectacle your opponents Carnage Tyrant, and if they were to use Blossoming Defense on a creature you would get neither the kill nor the mill.